# error while writing after reading same excel file - java poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am stuck up in this problem from two days and not getting any breakthrough. I use Java 8 and Apache POI for all excel related work. 
Basically, the process is shown in following diagram:

[image]

I want to "edit or append" values to existing sheet and not overwrite it. Considering there are 4 stages to above diagram, some of the codes that I used are:

**2nd stage (B): to write files from `file_x.xlsx`to `file_a.xlsx`:**

```
try{

    public FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c://file_path_file_a.xlsx"));
    public XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    public XSSFSheet sheet = newWorkbook.createSheet("vertical");


                for(String key : map_data.keySet()){
                    List<String> values = map_data.get(key);

                    // for values in each key, store it in sheet
                    for (String value:values){

                    // make instance of new row that will print data 
                    // simultaneously in two columns
                        Row newRow = sheet.createRow(row);

                        newRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(key); // 1st column
                        newRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(value); // 6th column

                        row++;
                        }

                }

                // write the contents of workbook into the excel file
                newWorkbook.write(out);

                // close all the respective files and workbooks
                out.close();
                newWorkbook.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This stage does the job correctly and I get desired output I want in file_a.xlsx.

Now comes the tricky part where I am failing. Stage 4 in the diagram shows that it wants to reads data from `file_y.xlsx` and appends values to existing `file_a.xlsx`.

It doesn't want to overwrite anything but want to add one more column to the existing excel file. But I am not able to code this out as cannot think of any good solution here and below given code fails.

**4th stage (D): to write files from `file_y.xlsx`to `file_a.xlsx`:**

```
try {

      public FileOutputStream output_excel_file = new FileOutputStream(new  File("c://file_path_file_a.xlsx"));
      public XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
      public XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("vertical");


            for (int i=0; i<qvm_1st_col.size(); i++) {

                if (error_text.contains(1st_col.get(i))) {

                    int index = error_text.indexOf(1st_col.get(i));
                    String value = dsps.get(index);

                    Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
                    row.createCell(12).setCellValue(value); // append values to 12th column


                }

            } // for loop

            output_excel_file.close();
            workbook.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So this code in D stage fails and algorithm stops right there.

**What I tried:**

Apart from codes above, I tried to read multiple answers for the same issue mentioned here on stack overflow, but I am not able to understand how it will solve my problem because I will be writing output excel file 2 times or may be more in future. Also, everything should happen in one single execution. So after `class 1` finishes work, `class 2` shall begin and so on.

I have to read the previous data and append more data from another reference files. I feel kinda lost on this one.

Thank you for your time.

**P.S:** 
I also read the output file somewhere between stage B and stage C to get some values in `arraylist`. That I do only to store some major generate keys from the output excel file.

Comment: I think you want to use `sheet.getRow(i)` instead of `sheet.createRow(i)` when you want to append  new column to an existing sheet.

Comment: In your last code `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();` creates a new empty workbook. So `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("vertical");` must fail since there is not a sheet named "vertical" in this new workbook. You say you have already read a Excel file in stage A. So in stage C you needs also to get a workbook from reading the "file_a.xlsx" and not creating a new workbook.

Comment: @AxelRichter So do you think that I only need to import that workbook from that class to my current class where I want to append column? can you elaborate this a little?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook

Comment: Thank you. That article helped me to append data in sheet. The only thing I am facing is output is now correctly displayed in new excel file that I created instead of same file. If i try to write everything in same file, then the file is getting corrupted due to some problem. I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: @ammoQ I did what you said and it worked fine. thank you.